# PyPDF2 Create a single page by appending two or more pages one after another using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to find a way to append two or more pages one after another and create a single page. I tried the following solution it creates a single paged pdf however the page 2 overlaps on page 1.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

file1 = PdfFileReader(open('good_old.pdf', "rb"))

output = PdfFileWriter()

page = file1.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(file1.getPage(1))
outputStream = open("great_new.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

I just want the two pages to appear one after another but as a single page, if the height of the two pages is x. the output pdf will have a single page with 2x height.